# What is a better way to prevent deletion of all sub documents when at least one is required in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Take a simple schema defined in mongoose as below:

```
const Person = new Schema({
username: {
    type: String,
    index: true,
},
roles: [{
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Role',
    required: [true,
        'Role is required'],
}],
})
```

When you save a new record without supplying at least one role, MongoDB will throw an error that roles is required.

I have another piece of code where you can update (add or remove) roles from the roles array. However, I am able to remove all roles using the snippet below.

```
Person.findOneAndUpdate({_id: 'some id'}, {
        $pull: {
            roles: {
                $in: [...list of ids,]
            }
        }
    }, {new: true}).populate('roles').exec()
```

Assuming I list all roles that person has, I will remove them leaving that person with no roles.

How do I enforce the earlier requirement that role is required? Is there a simple hack or should I just write a piece of code to validate this deletion and enforce it myself?

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you are able to remove all the roles, and the required validation is not working because validation is implemented as internal middleware within Mongoose and middleware don't get executed during an update. You can read more about it [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html).

If you are using **MongoDB 4.0 or above**, you can use `runValidators: true` option in an `update` call. You can read more about runValidators option in [Mongoose Update Validators documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html#update-validators).

You can try below code (I haven't tested it though):

```
Person.findOneAndUpdate({_id: 'some id'}, {
        $pull: {
            roles: {
                $in: [...list of ids,]
            }
        }
    }, {new: true, runValidators: true}).populate('roles').exec()
```

> According to [official Mongoose docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html#update-validators-only-run-for-some-operations), Update validators work on
> below operators ( and MongoDB versoins):
>
> - $set
> - $unset
> - $push (>= 4.8.0)
> - $addToSet (>= 4.8.0)
> - $pull (>= 4.12.0)
> - $pullAll (>= 4.12.0)

Or what you can also do is setup a `Pre` hook for `findOneAndUpdate`,

```
// Pre hook for `findOneAndUpdate`
ClientSchema.pre('findOneAndUpdate', function(next) {
  this.options.runValidators = true;
  next();
});
```

If you have **MongoDB < 4.0**

Then what you can do is find the document using `.findOne()`, set the new properties in the document, and try to save it again using `.save()`. This should run the validation.